# how do i access these indices

Tags: java

i have a List as follows:

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
x.add("Date : Jul 15, 2010 Income : 8500 Expenses : 0");
x.add("Date : Aug 23, 2010 Income : 0 Expenses : 6500");
x.add("Date : Jul 15, 2010 Income : 0 Expenses : 4500");
```

i now want to access these indeces as follows:

```
int index1 = x.indexOf("Date : Aug 23, 2010");
//1

int index2 = x.indexOf("Date : Jul 15, 2010");
//0

int index3 = x.lastIndexOf("Date : Jul 15, 2010");
//2
```

Any help? Thank’s in advance.

**This is the solution i was looking for:**

```
// traverse the List forward so as to get the first index
private static int getFirstIndex(List<String> theList, String toFind) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
        if (theList.get(i).startsWith(toFind)) {
            return i;                
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// traverse the List backwards so as to get the last index
private static int getLastIndex(List<String> theList, String toFind) {
    for (int i = theList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (theList.get(i).startsWith(toFind)) {
            return i;               
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Those two methods will fulfill exactly the requirements that i wanted.Thanks all!

Comment: I'm afraid you have to iterate through the `List` and check every item with a regex or at least compare substrings if it's always in the same form

Comment: `Map`? It should help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to replace your `String`s with a class with `Date`, `Income`, and `Expenses` getters/setters? That would allow for much cleaner code.

Comment: But the strings in the list are different than those for which he's looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a function

```
public static int getIndexOf(List<String> array, String stringToFind)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
       if(array.get(i).contains(stringToFind);
           return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Simply iterate through the list, search for string, and return what you want. Otherwise return -1 if not found.

Sorry fixed more spelling issues. And he presented stringly question and I gave stringly answer. If statement can be modified to suit whatever search style he wants. And yes I call my lists array due to sloppy typing.

Comment: Technically this is a correct answer, but I'm afraid it will drive the OP in the wrong direction (that of Stringly-typed programming).

Comment: Micro-nitpick: why is the `List` parameter called `array`? ;-)

Comment: Major-nitpick: `String stringToFind` :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and for the time you took to implement the solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with any built-in method.

You have two options:

1. iterate over the list manually and use `startsWith()` (or `indexOf()`, depending on what exactly you want) *or*
2. change your data structure to a `Map<String,String>` and use the date as the key.

Generally speaking, you're trying to use `String` as a structured data type, which it isn't. It's unstructured, general-purpose data. That's not really the best data type to handle in your code.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` is the wrong data structure for what you appear to want to do. You should consider parsing the string into two pieces, a `Date` and another object (`CashFlow` perhaps?) and use a `Map` to relate the two.

Then you could do the following:

```
//Parse the string into a Date and CashFlow object
Date august = ...
CashFlow flow = ...
Map<Date, CashFlow> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(august, flow);
//Later...
CashFlow c = map.get(august);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I really had to do that without a `Map`, I would do;

```
public int getIndex(List<String> x, String key)
{
    boolean found = false;
    int index = 0;
    for (String s: x)
    {
      if (s.startsWith(key))
      {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
      index++;
    }
    if (!found)
    {
      index = -1;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: In the `!found` case I'd return `-1` to be consistent with `indexOf()` (unless you know that for this usecase, an exception is more useful, but that depends a lot on the context).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and for the time you took to implement the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a new Class like this:

```
class SpecialArrayList<String> extends ArrayList<String>{

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            java.lang.String t = (java.lang.String)this.get(i);
            if (t.startsWith((java.lang.String) o)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and then you can use

```
List<String> x = new SpecialArrayList<String>();
```

But as mentioned in other answers it's not the best style to look for strings like that. And you would change a standard behaviour for the "indexOf" method. Better would be to write this "search" or "startswith" function with a clear name that is not used with another standard meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and for the time you took to implement the solution.